# Valgrind errors from dynamically allocated arrays in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

The program is aimed to take a dynamically allocated array and return a new dynamically allocated array with double the size that copies the values in the first one and leaves the rest uninitialized. However, it's getting valgrind errors in main(). Any suggestions on how to fix the memory issues?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int * doubleSize(int * p, int & cap) {
    //create dynamically allocated double size array
    int *doubleSize = new int(cap * 2);
    
    //store old array values into new array
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        doubleSize[i] = p[i];
    }

    cap = cap * 2; 

    delete[] p; //deallocate old memory

    return doubleSize;
}

int main() {
    int cap = 3;
    int *p = new int(cap);
    //initialize an array
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        p[i] = i;
    }
    
    int *s = doubleSize(p, cap);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << s[i] << endl;
    }

    //deallocate memory
    delete p;
    delete s;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `new int[cap*2]` and `new int[cap]`?  If so, you should have `delete [] s;` at the end, and do not `delete p;` at all.

Comment: `delete p;` two problems: `p` was previously deleted in `doubleSize` and you need `delete[]`. Second problem is repeated at `delete s;`.

Comment: Of course the *real* way to fix this problem is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems in the code:

```
int *p = new int(cap);
```

and

```
int *doubleSize = new int(cap * 2);
```

both allocate a single `int` with the value `cap` or `cap * 2`

Since arrays of `int` are expected by the rest of the code, these need to be corrected to

```
int *p = new int[cap];
```

and

```
int *doubleSize = new int[cap * 2];
```

Then

```
delete p;
delete s;
```

must be changed to

```
delete[] p;
delete[] s;
```

in order to correctly `delete` arrays.

But!

```
delete[] p;
```

already happened back in `doubleSize` when the array was replaced. It could be removed, but the code would be cleaner with

```
p = doubleSize(p, cap);
```

and the variable `s` being removed instead.